# Graph represented as adjacency list, as binary tree, is it possible?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, time-complexity, binary-tree

apologies first, english is not my first language.

So here's my understanding on graph that's represented as adjancey list: It's usually used for sparse graph, which is the case for most of graphs, and it uses V (number of vertex) lists. so, V head pointers + 2e (# of edges) nodes for undirected graph. Therefore, space complexity = O(E+V)
Since any node can have upto V-1 edges (excluding itself) it has time complexity of O(V) to check a node's adjacency.

As to check all the edges, it takes O(2e + V) so O(v + e)
Now, since it's mostly used for sparse graph, it's rarely O(v) to check adjacency, but simply the number of edges a given vertex has (which is O(V) at worst since V-1 is the possible maximum)

What I'm wondering is, is it possible to make the list (the edge nodes) binary tree? So to find out whether node A is adjacent to node B, time complexity would be O(logn) and not linear O(n).
If it is possible, is it actually done quite often? Also, what is that kind of data structure called? I've been googling if such combinations are possible but couldn't find anything. I would be very grateful if anyone could explain this to me in detail as i'm new to data structure. Thank you.

Edit: I know binary search can be performed on arrays. I'm talking about linked list representation, I thought I made it obvious when I said heads to the lists but wow

Comment: Why not represent them as hash table? With a proper management of the fill-factor and a pre-allocation of the slots, searching in a hash table is O(1).

Comment: How do you represent it in binary tree? What is contained in a tree node? Can it handle directed graph, with multiple edges / self edges? I doubt if it really can answer query like "Is node A adjacent to node B" in O(lg n)...

Comment: no need to use complicated data structures. Sort adjacency list for each vertex and use binary search

Comment: This is most likely a sparse graph and with multiple vertices I doubt i can use hashtable.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list#Implementation_details

Comment: shole I don't think you even understood the question but trying so pathetically hard to sound like you know something. I would have mentioned selfloop or multiple edges if that was the graph of interest. I don't think you even know what adjacency ist is

Comment: I'm talking about adjacency list implemented with linked list, not arrays. I said head pointers

Comment: use [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/](std::vector) from C++ or its equivalent from any other language

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason the adjacency list for each vertex couldn't be stored as a binary tree, but there are tradoffs.

As you say, this adjacency list representation is often used for sparse graphs. Often, "sparse graph" means that a particular vertex is adjacent to few others. So your "adjacency list" for a particular vertex would be very small. Whereas it's true that binary search is O(log n) and sequential search is O(n), when n is very small sequential search is faster. I've seen cases where sequential search beats binary search when n is smaller than 16. It depends on the implementation, of course, but don't count on binary search being faster for small lists.

Another thing to think about is memory. Linked list overhead is one pointer per node. Unless, of course, you're using a doubly linked list. Binary tree overhead is two pointers per node. Perhaps not a big deal, but if you're trying to represent a very large graph, that extra pointer will become important.

If the graph will be updated frequently at run time, you have to take that into account, too. Adding a new edge to a linked list of edges is an O(1) operation. But adding an edge to a binary tree will require O(log n). And you want to make sure you keep that tree balanced. An unbalanced tree starts to act like a linked list.

So, yes, you could make your adjacency lists binary trees. You have to decide whether it's worth the extra effort, based on your application's speed requirements and the nature of your data.

Comment: thank you very much sir. Is the above combination (adjacency list as linked list, and linear find adjacency) the most popular structure in the real world?

Comment: @Tearin: I don't know if it's the most popular structure. There are many possible structures, each of which has its own strengths and weaknesses. I personally have used one with a linked list, and also one with a sorted array. It depends on whether you're optimizing for speed of access, speed of update, memory, etc. Use whichever structure is appropriate for your application.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I am terribly sorry to bother you again but would linked list as binary tree have strength too? I was thinking if a node had more than maybe 32~100+ adjacencies, dynamic array/binary tree would be better.  And if  add/delete operations were frequent, since it costs O(n) to add in dynamic array to move things around, make a new array if it's full, etc. and O(n) for delete too, binary tree would be better since it's O(log2n)  for both cases. Am I on the right track, or is such case so infeasible and highly unlikely?

Comment: If I wrote about such structure as a possible data structure and list its strengths would someone like you (expert) or professor think it's stupid? I think what I want to ask is  if you have seen or think such structure is desirable in at least a few real world implementations, or it is very unlikely or only theoretical. I would be very grateful if you could answer this. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It just occurred to me it's probably a stupid idea and not worth listing it, since if there are a lot of insertions/deletions, binary tree can be skewed. And it would waste a lot of space and slow on top of that since it would be O(n) is this valid?